# Load image to div tag by using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a problem to find a solution, can you help me how to add image to div tag by using jquery and ajax? I tried various solutions but I could not done.

I need to pull the image from steel_agg_bof_flash_en.html that can be opened as a xml file, and this is data interfaces information that I needed for this task.

I'm working on localhost and this file (steel_agg_bof_flash_en.html) is in my root folder

```html
<data>
  <labels>
    <closebtn><![CDATA[]]></closebtn>
    <path></path>
    <addbtn><![CDATA[add hotspots]]></addbtn>
    <deletebtn><![CDATA[delete hotspots]]></deletebtn>
    <resetbtn><![CDATA[reset hotspots]]></resetbtn>
  </labels>
  <basics>
    <lg></lg>
    <clickmapid>contentbean:9492</clickmapid>
    <adminMode>0</adminMode>
    <imgpath>/linkableblob/internet_en/9492/image/steel_agg_bof_flash_en-image.jpg</imgpath>
    <format>landscape</format>
    <title><![CDATA[]]></title>
  </basics>
  <hotspots>
    <hotspot>
      <hsid>clickMap_item_9510</hsid>
      <title><![CDATA[Optimal design ]]></title>
      <position><![CDATA[350,469,247]]></position>
    </hotspot>
 
    ....
  </hotspots>
</data>
```

This is my current code and what I tried to do, but doesnt work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="" class="content_item">
   <h1>BOF vessel </h1>
   <!-- class should be either "portrait" or no class for "landscape" -->
   <div id="clickMap">
     <div id="clickMapFlashContainer"></div>
       
       <div id="clickMapFlash" style="width:auto"></div>
     </div>
     <div id="clickMap_item_default" class="clickMapItem text">
       <div><p>Due to long-standing contact with customers RHI has detailed knowledge of the requirements that steelworkers place on refractories. This is why RHI has been involved in the development of package and system solutions for many years und nowadays offers customized high-end solutions for basically all individual customer requirements.</p></div>
     </div>
 </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "steel_agg_bof_flash_en.html",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function xmlParser(xml) {

              $(xml).find('basics').each(function () {

                  var img = $(this).find('imgpath').text();

                  $('<img />')
                     .attr('src', "" + img + "")         // ADD IMAGE PROPERTIES.
                     .width('200px').height('200px')

                     .appendTo($('#clickMapFlash'));     // ADD THE IMAGE TO DIV.
                });
            }
        });
    });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: We need more information as to where it's going wrong. What does your script do now? Are you getting any errors in your console window when running the code?  Is your `$.each()` looping at all?

Comment: I don't have any errors, but script does not executed at all. However, when I wrote this line of code - error : function {
    alert ( ' error loading image ' ) 
}, that part of code is executed.

Comment: You mean  that if you add the error handler to the ajax request, that is in fact handled? If so, there's something wrong with the request itself, maybe  the path to the file is not correct?

Comment: Yes, error handler is executed, but success is not.

Comment: Okay so like I said, your request is faulty. Check what's wrong. If I had to guess, it would be your URL parameter (it's incomplete). Check what request is logged in your consolebrowser (in Chrome it's under Network)

Comment: is ajax url is dynamic data created by PHP or just static file saved as .html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the relative URL to absolute in **imgpath** node:

```
<imgpath>http://www.fopv.org.uk/images/works.jpg</imgpath>
```

Just to be sure you are not trying to load non-existing image on your file system.

It seems that your code works:

https://jsfiddle.net/ae031p5q/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and solution, this is acceptable, but I am not sure how good is to put the absolute path of image

Comment: You don't need to use absolute path, it is just example to get know whether your code works properly. Just place the image on you file system, rely on relative path from XML

Comment: How can you load the image if you're working on localhost and this file (steel_agg_bof_flash_en.html) is in your root folder ? The image shoul also be located in your root folder:

`[root]/linkableblob/internet_en/9492/image/steel_agg_bof_flash_en-image.jpg`

Comment: Ok, I found a solution, this path is good <imgpath>
../../../../../../linkableblob/internet_en/9492/image/steel_agg_bof_flash_en-image.jpg
</imgpath>

Comment: I have just one more question about this situation, is it possible to set a image as a background of clickMapFlash. Can you help me?

Comment: It will look the follows:

'$('#clickMapFlash').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');'

Comment: However, you should also set dimensions of the div:

Comment: `$('#clickMapFlash').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')');.width('200px').height('200px');`

Comment: test.html:939 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . , but doesnt metter, you help me a lot, I will found a solution. Thanks a lot one more time.